# Type '{ children: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, react-props

I have a parent and a child functional component as below.
The parent component is NavBar.tsx

```
    interface NavBarType {
  top: number;
}

const NavBar = (props: NavBarType) => {
  const scrollDown = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: props.top,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  return (
    <AppBar
      position="static"
      sx={{
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "flex-end",
        background: "#7E685A",
      }}
    >
      <Link onClick={scrollDown}>About</Link>

      <Link onClick={scrollDown}>Skills</Link>
      <Link onClick={scrollDown}>Education</Link>
      <Link onClick={scrollDown}>Experience</Link>
      <Link onClick={scrollDown}>Contact Me</Link>
      <Link onClick={scrollDown}>Resume</Link>
    </AppBar>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

The child component is Link.tsx

```
interface LinkType {
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
}

const Link: React.FC<LinkType> = (props: LinkType) => {
  return <Typography onClick={props.onClick} className={classes.Link} />;
};

export default Link;
```

`<Link>` in the parent component is throwing an error

> Type '{ children: string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkType'.   Property 'children' does
> not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkType'.

Not sure why is it throwing this error. I checked the types and all. Couldn't identify it. If someone could help me out, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.FC` no longer includes the `children` property in it's type, so in this case, your `LinkType` interface only accepts an `onClick` and nothing else. Also, your `Typography` element does not have children passed into it either, so to fix this, you'd need to make a couple of changes:

1. Add `children` to LinkType

```
interface LinkType {
  children: ReactNode;
  onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
}
```

2. Render passed children on `Typography`

```
const Link: React.FC<LinkType> = (props: LinkType) => {
  return <Typography onClick={props.onClick} children={props.children} className={classes.Link} />;
};
```

OR

```
const Link: React.FC<LinkType> = (props: LinkType) => {
  return (
    <Typography onClick={props.onClick} className={classes.Link}>
     {props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
};
```